# How can I obtain the log-likelihood value in a OLS estimation?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, least-squares, panel-data

So, in some papers using panel data, I noticed that in the estimate results inherent a pooled OLS regression, they report the value of the log-likelihood.

I was wondering how this is possible, in Stata, since OLS and ML are two separate estimators.

I can I hence obtain the log-likelihood value, in Stata, when running a pooled OLS regression (for panel data). Which is the Stata command I should use?

Answer (score 1):

The OLS solution coincides with MLE for multivariate normal variable. That is if we assume that $y_i\sim N(x_i\beta,\sigma^2)$ with data $(y_i,x_i)$ the MLE solution for $\beta$ coincides with OLS. Hence when reporting MLE value for OLS solution the normal distribution model is used.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! However, this does not fully reply to my answer. Apart from the normality assumption, I asked how to obtain the log-likelihood value in Stata when performing a pooled OLS (i.e. which command should I use). For instance, to be more clear, see this paper: http://ageconsearch.umn.edu/bitstream/149006/2/Paper%20submitted%20to%20AAEA%202013_Xueting%20Zhao.pdf How were the log likelihood values obtained in the panel estimates of Table 1??? Thank you! :)

Comment: Pooled OLS is the same regression model which I described in my answer. Write down the MLE for it and notice where you can substitute residuals (additional hint, the MLE estimate for $\sigma$ is also calculated from residuals).

Comment: again, thank you for your prompt answer.
Also, do you know if with Stata I can also perform a FE panel estimation with ML? For the RE there is the command "xtreg..., mle", whcih provides the ML estimation with a random effect, but for the FE there is no such command..:/

Comment: No, I do not know Stata.

Comment: This answer doesn't look correct, because the log-likelihood depends on $\hat\sigma$ and that differs between the MLE and OLS solutions.

Answer (score 1):

For pooled OLS you can use

`reg y x`

to obtain the log likelihood of the model

`estat ic`

another option is to use

`glm y x`